# Is there any app that auto fills radio buttons with default values in another app?

Tags: android, user-input, autofill

I have to submit medical info in an Android app. Everytime the radio button for the question 'whether taking medicine regularly ' is to be put as 'yes'. It's so repetitive as there are many such radio buttons to be filled for a patient which always have the same answer. Can anyone guide how to autofill these please?

Got a hint to edit XML file of.the app with default answers but I cannot find them on my phone and don't know how to edit such files even if I find